# using fitdist from fitdistplus with binomial distribution

Tags: r, distribution

I just discovered the `fitdistrplus` package, and I have it up and running with a Poisson distribution, etc.. but I get stuck when trying to use a binomial:

```
set.seed(20)
#Binomial distributed, mean score of 2
scorebinom <- rbinom(n=40,size=8,prob=.25)


fitBinom=fitdist(data=scorebinom, dist="binom", start=list(size=8, prob=mean(scorebinom)/8))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in fitdist(data = scorebinom, dist = "binom", start = list(size = 8,  : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

I see a lot of documentation from this package about the negative binomial distribution, but not much about the binomial.  This function does appear to support this distribution (though `fitdistr` in `MASS` does not).

Any thoughts?

Comment: The issue seems to be arising from the MLE routine called inside of `fitdist` - there is a (somewhat unhelpful) list of output codes in the **Value** section of the helpfile `?mledist`. I have run into errors like this from time to time when fitting parameters, and it's usually a pain to track down the exact cause. You might try playing around with the `custom.optim` function `fitdist` passes to `optim`. Sometimes I have better luck with *Simulated Annealing* than the default algorithm used by `optim`. ...

Comment: For example, this returns parameter estimates, but not standard errors, and still produces warnings: `fitdist(data=x,dist="binom",start=list(size=8, prob=mean(x)/8),custom.optim=function(...){optim(..., method="SANN")})` (where I renamed your vector `scorebinom` as `x` for convenience).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Won't you always know the number of trials (i.e., the size parameter)? If so, then try

```
fitBinom=fitdist(data=scorebinom, dist="binom", fix.arg=list(size=8), start=list(prob=0.3))
```

to estimate p and its error.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  It seems odd to me that it can't estimate the size parameter when I supply it for the starting value, but I suppose it would make sense that it should be required in a fixed argument list.  I think the `fitdist` documentation can be more explicit here.